# Is it feasible to run many of dynamic SQL queries on DataTable object

Tags: c#, performance, datatable, dataview, rowfilter

A DataTable object, say Stocks(Ticker, Sector, Price)
I want to support dynamic queries (i.e. not known at compile time)
like this "Ticker like '%A' and price>7.50 "

I understand that DataView.RowFilter supports certain degree of SQL expression
but the problem is every time you set .RowFilter, the DataView rebuild the internal index, and that's too much overhead

And I try not to query SQL Server because
1) it's a small dataset and doesn't change much at runtime, thus can be in memory
2) I want to evaluate tens of thousands of these free-form SQL expressions

What options do I have? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Thx jp2code for DataTable.Select

I haven't verified, but this link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/807941/DataTable-Select-is-Slow
says building a DataView will create an index which appears to favorably affect DataTable.Select, so I will just store all data in a DataTable object and create a DataView for each of the columns that will be involved in queries.

Answer (score 0):

Call **GetData(table)** below once, then every other time call the overload **GetData(table, sqlFilter)**:

```
    private DataTable m_table;

    public DataTable GetData(string sqlCmd)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        return table;
    }

    public DataTable GetData(DataTable table, string sqlFilter)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlFilter))
        {
            var copy = table.Clone();
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Select(sqlFilter))
            {
                var newRow = copy.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    newRow[i] = row.ItemArray[i];
                }
                copy.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
            return copy;
        }
        return table;
    }
```

There may be other ways, but this should get you started.

Comment: jp2code, thank you very much! reminded me of DataTable.Select, I will update original post.